# How to speed up MYSQL Query with JOIN and BETWEEN where clause?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, join, query-optimization

**The query**

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp29174960179_posts.*
    FROM wp29174960179_posts
         JOIN wp29174960179_plugin_wpf_products_attribute_79_numbers pan ON pan.product_id = wp29174960179_posts.ID
    WHERE pan.number BETWEEN 10 and 10000
    ORDER BY wp29174960179_posts.post_date ASC LIMIT 0, 9;
```

This query so slow **(takes 2s)**. 
Expected execution time **<= 100ms**

There is **80 000 records** in **`wp29174960179_plugin_wpf_products_attribute_79_numbers`** table.

And **100 000 records** in **`wp29174960179_posts`** table

There are **2 indexes** for **`wp29174960179_plugin_wpf_products_attribute_79_numbers`** table

```
ix__number__product_id (product_id, number)
ix__product_id__number (number, product_id)
```

There is **index** for **`*wp29174960179_posts`** for **ID** field

Despite these indexes. Query takes **2-3** seconds

**SQL full Code Snippet link:**

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4Vk97FhArBVJ1Eb1BAubNB/0#&togetherjs=8KQQacE4Vt

Comment: `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` is costly.  See how fast it runs without it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It *looks like* you have a 1-N relationships between posts and pans, and you are trying to get the posts for which rows in pan exists that satisify a given condition.

If so, you could try and rewrite the query with an `EXISTS` subquery:

```
select p.*
from wp29174960179_posts p
where exists (
    select 1 
    from wp29174960179_plugin_wpf_products_attribute_79_numbers n 
    where n.product_id = p.id and n.number between 10 and 10000
)
order by p.post_date 
limit 9
```

This technique avoids the need for aggregation in the outer query. This query should be able to take advantage of an index on `wp29174960179_plugin_wpf_products_attribute_79_numbers(product_id, number)`.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the outer sorting is causing the performance issue.   Your query and indexes look reasonable.  The question is:  can we trick MySQL into avoiding the sort?

Start with the rewrite that GMB suggests.  This also has the nice characteristic that it does not return duplicated values:

```
select p.*
from wp29174960179_posts p
where exists (select 1 
              from wp29174960179_plugin_wpf_products_attribute_79_numbers n 
              where n.product_id = p.id and
                    n.number between 10 and 10000
             )
order by p.post_date 
limit 9;
```

Then try the following indexes:

- `wp29174960179_posts(post_date, id)`
- `wp29174960179_plugin_wpf_products_attribute_79_numbers(product_id, number)`

The hope is that the posts table will be scanned in `post_date` order and the first 9 matching rows will be returned.  Fingers crossed.